# post request in dashboard scope doesn`t work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

authenticated user should be able to add wallet address via form at his dashboard. In my routes

```
scope '/dashboard', module: :dashboard do
  get '/', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/dashboard'
  post '/eth_address', to: 'dashboard#eth_address'
end
```

My form

```
<%= form_for eth_address_path do |f| %>
          <%= f.label :eth_address %>
          <%= f.text_field :eth_address %>
          <%= f.submit "Save" %>
      <% end %>
```

in views/dashboard/dashboard/index.html.erb

And my simple controller

```
Dashboard::DashboardController
```

in

```
controllers/dashboard/dashboard_controller.rb
```

with method

```
def eth_address
  eth_addr = params[:eth_address]
  EthereumWallet.create(user_id: current_user.id,
                      address: eth_addr)
end
```

Rails routes of dashboard

```
dashboard GET  /dashboard(.:format)  dashboard/dashboard#index
 eth_address POST /dashboard/eth_address(.:format) dashboard/dashboard#eth_address
```

and after submit i see this:

```
No route matches [POST] "/dashboard"
```

I have no idea why it asks me for POST request from /dashboard.

Thanks

Comment: Show your routes.  rake routes

Comment: added routes to question

Comment: form_for :eth_address_path

Answer (score 0):

Use alias for eth_address

```
post '/eth_address', to: 'dashboard#eth_address', as: :eth_address
```

Comment: problem stil exists.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change

```
form_for
```

on new

```
form_with
```

and new form

```
 <%= form_with url: :eth_address_path do |f| %>
          <%= f.label :eth_address %>
          <%= f.text_field :eth_address %>
          <%= f.submit "Save" %>
      <% end %>
```

works pretty nice